# How do I loop through this JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following JSON returned from a PHP script

```
var data ={ 
            "first thing"  :["1","2"],
            "second thing" :["5","7"],
            "third thing"  :["8","2"]
           };
```

I know that I can access the items like so:

```
console.log(data["first thing"]);
```

But, I need to iterate through them and apply them to some html, and the object names are going to change so how do I just have the loop systematically go through them and apply as needed? Basically I first need to loop through and apply the names, then I will later loop again and apply the value pairs.

```
 processResults:function(data){
         $('.thisclass').each(function(){
             $(this).html('put first json name here, so "first thing"')
             //then continue to loop through and apply next object name
         });
 }
```

Then in the next loop I will need to do something like this:

```
 processResults:function(data){
         $('.nextclass').each(function(){
             $(this).html('put first of two values here, so "1"')
             //then continue to loop through and apply next object value
         });
 }
```

The problem is I don't know how to do it without specifying the object name in bracket notation!

Comment: [`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) or [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 3):

You may try this (Since it's tagged with `jQuery`):

```
$.each(yourObject, function(key, element){
    //key will be like "first thing" and so-
    //element will be an array.

    //it's true that yourObject[key] == element
    $.each(element, function(arrayIndex, arrayElement) {
        //process each arrayElement here
        //it's true that element[arrayIndex] == arrayElement
    })
})
```

Comment: Okay perfect, now if I also want the index or just a plain count of the object name I am on, would I just need to add my own increment variable here or is there some other way?

Comment: If you want the index, arrayIndex has the index inside the array. I did not write well the code, let me update it. arrayIndex is the index you want. callbacks to `each` take 2 arguments: the first is the index in the array (if the iterated object is an array), or key in the object (if the iterated object is not an array). adding your own counter will do the job, but you already have that counter as the first parameter when iterating over an array. EDIT: I edited the code. see the comment where it says: element[arrayIndex]==arrayElement.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data ={ 
    "first thing"  :["1","2"],
    "second thing" :["5","7"],
    "third thing"  :["8","2"]
};

$.each(data, function (key, arr) {
    console.log(key);
    var i = 0;
    for(i; i < arr.length; i++) {
        console.log(arr[i]);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var data ={
        "first thing"  :["1","2"],
        "second thing" :["5","7"],
        "third thing"  :["8","2"]
       };
//this will print all the key names
for (var key in data) {
  console.log(key);
}

//this will print the key values.
for (var key in data) {
  console.log(data[key]);
}
```

Now you just need to adapt it to your necessity.